# Can I get a patent from a device which was made with open source parts?

Tags: patentability

Can I get a patent for a device which was made with open source parts? I have some concept of a device but it's made with Arduino and other (Arduino-friendly) components. Is it possible to pass all appropriate steps to get a patent?

Comment: @Nick Alexeev How about the Meta site? Although strictly off topic this is interesting and very relevant to electronic design.

Comment: AFAIK if you have a new and unique combination of parts that no one else has used then you could get a patent.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you use open source parts is really irrelevant. What matters is whether your invention is useful, novel and non-obvious. Useful means it has fulfills a purpose. Novel means it hasn't been thought of before. Non-obvious means someone skilled in the field wouldn't think it straightforward. This is a brief explanation, there are more rigorous legal definitions.